# node.js - Sort JSON objects by a value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this JSON file on my server:

```
{"1504929411112":{"name":"user1","score":"10"},"1504929416574":{"name":"2nduser","score":"14"},"1504929754610":{"name":"usr3","score":"99"},"1504929762722":{"name":"userfour","score":"40"},"1504929772310":{"name":"user5","score":"7"}}
```

Assuming I have parsed this file:

```
var json = JSON.parse(getJSONFile());
```

How can I now sort each object in the `json` variable by the `score` property?
None of the array sorting functions work for me as `json` is not an array.

Comment: Object properties don't have any order, so you'll _have_ to create an array if you want that data sorted.

Comment: @MattGregory How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since these are objects' properties, their order is usually unknown and not guaranteed. To sort them by some internal property, you would first have to change the Object into an Array, for example:

```
const json = JSON.parse(getJsonFile());

const jsonAsArray = Object.keys(json).map(function (key) {
  return json[key];
})
.sort(function (itemA, itemB) {
  return itemA.score < itemB.score;
});
```

For more, see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: *They are sorted by their keys automatically* That's not exactly right. It's better to just say "their order is undefined".

Answer (score 3):

```
var ob = { "fff": { "name": "user1", "score": "10" }, "bbbb": { "name": "user4", "score": "14" }, "dddd": { "name": "user2", "score": "99" }, "cccc": { "name": "user5", "score": "40" }, "aaaa": { "name": "user3", "score": "7" } };


Object.keys(ob).map(key => ({ key: key, value: ob[key] })).sort((first, second) => (first.value.name < second.value.name) ? -1 : (first.value.name > second.value.name) ? 1 : 0 ).forEach((sortedData) => console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedData)));
```

Comment: it's preferable to use `localeCompare`.